# Regex to match path

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I trying to validate user entered string is correct relative path or not.

- It should not start with **assets/**
- It should not end with **/**
- It should not end with any file extension like .html or .php or .jpg
- It should not contain dot **.**

I am trying with below regex, but it is not working correctly.

```
^([a-z]:)*(\/*(\.*[a-z0-9]+\/)*(\.*[a-z0-9]+))
```

My test cases

**Valid path**

- sample/hello/images
- sample/hello_vid/user/data
- test/123/user_live/images

**Invalid path**

- assets/sample/hello/images
- sample/hello_vid/user/data/
- test/123/user_live/images/index.html
- hii/sk.123/data
- ok/bye/last.exe

Comment: Do you need it to be a regex only or can use the methods of System.IO.Path?

Comment: "It should not contain a dot "   That will be enough to exclude the .jpg, .pdf etc

Comment: Paths can contain many more characters than `[a-z0-9]+`. Consider using `\w+`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you also want to match the underscore, you could add it to the character class. To prevent matching `assets/` at the start, you could use a negative lookahead.

```
^(?!assets/)[a-z0-9_]+(?:/[a-z0-9_]+)+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!assets/)` Assert what is directly to the right is not `assets/`
- `[a-z0-9_]+` Repeat 1+ times any of the listed, including the underscore
- `(?:/[a-z0-9_]+)+` Repeat 1+ times a `/` and 1+ times any of the listed
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f!assets%2f%29%5ba-z0-9_%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%2f%5ba-z0-9_%5d%2b%29%2b%5cr%3f%24&i=sample%2fhello%2fimages%0d%0asample%2fhello_vid%2fuser%2fdata%0d%0atest%2f123%2fuser_live%2fimages%0d%0a%0d%0aassets%2fsample%2fhello%2fimages%0d%0asample%2fhello_vid%2fuser%2fdata%2f%0d%0atest%2f123%2fuser_live%2fimages%2findex.html%0d%0ahii%2fsk.123%2fdata%0d%0aok%2fbye%2flast.exe&o=m)

Or you could use `\w` instead of the character class

```
^(?!assets/)\w+(?:/\w+)+$
```

Comment: Why this answer is down voted? Please atleast mention the reason for the same. I'm sure the answerer can rectify the stuff if you provide valid flaw in the answer. I don't see any BTW.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative "readable" approach ;)

```
public static bool IsValidPath(this string path)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path)) return false;
    if (path.StartsWith("assets/")) return false;
    if (path.EndsWith("/")) return false;
    if (path.Contains(".")) return false;

    return true;
}

// Usage
var value = "sample/hello/images";
if (value.IsValidPath())
{
    // use the value...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for your test cases.

```
Regex explained:
^(?!assets/) # It should not start with assets/
[^\.]+       # It should not contain dot (file extensions contain a dot)
(?<!/)$      # It should not end with /

Regex in one line:
^(?!assets/)[^\.]+(?<!/)$
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try below regex to achieve your purpose:

```
^(?!assets\/)[^.]*?$(?<!\/\r?$)
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`^, $`** - Represents start and end of line respectively.
>
> **`(?!assets\/)`** - Represents a negative look-ahead not matching the test strings which start with `assets\`.
>
> **`[^.]*?`** - Matches everything **lazily** other than `.`. This case will cover the file extensions too so no need to check them again.
>
> **`(?<!\/\r?$)`** - Represents negative look behind not matching the test string if it contains `\` as the last character.

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f!assets%5c%2f%29%5b%5e.%5d*%3f%24%28%3f%3c!%5c%2f%5cr%3f%24%29&i=sample%2fhello%2fimages%0d%0asample%2fhello_vid%2fuser%2fdata%0d%0atest%2f123%2fuser_live%2fimages%0d%0aassets%2fsample%2fhello%2fimages%0d%0asample%2fhello_vid%2fuser%2fdata%2f%0d%0atest%2f123%2fuser_live%2fimages%2findex.html%0d%0ahii%2fsk.123%2fdata%0d%0aok%2fbye%2flast.exe&o=m)

[image: Pictorial Representation]
**Implementation in C#**

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"^(?!assets\/)[^.]*?$(?<!\/\r?$)";
        string input = @"sample/hello/images
sample/hello_vid/user/data
test/123/user_live/images
assets/sample/hello/images
sample/hello_vid/user/data/
test/123/user_live/images/index.html
hii/sk.123/data
ok/bye/last.exe";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

You can find the sample run of the above code in [**here.**](https://onlinegdb.com/S1NmCDkpL)

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should be fine for the scenarios you have mentioned:

```
^((?!(assets\/))(?! )([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+(?<! )\/(?! ))+[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+)$
```

In addition to the scenarios in the questions, I have also taken care of a folder name not starting or ending with spaces.